# Use sub-elements inside XSLT file?

Tags: xml, xslt, dtd

I'm having trouble. Firstly I apologize if the words I use aren't the correct words, I'm quite new to XML.

In my assignment, I was asked to create a DTD, XML and XSLT file. I have the DTD and XML file finished, and I'm working on the XSLT file. Everything is working, I just don't know how to access the elements that are inside other elements. Here is the code so it'll be easier to explain.

XML; (Only a part of it for an example)

```
<entry id='c01'>
    <MetaTags>Business</MetaTags>   
    <title><brand>HP Pavilion</brand><name>550-112NA</name></title>
    <Description>While other towers have been standing still, HP has revolutionized the category. From magnified performance and reliability, to its stylish redesign, this HP Pavilion is the best thing to happen to towers in over 20 years.</Description>
    <Price>€579</Price>
    <Image src="Image1.jpg"/>
    <Specs>
        <CPU>A10-8750 APU</CPU>
        <GPU>Radeon R7</GPU>
        <RAM>8 GB DDR3</RAM>
        <Storage><HDD> 2TB </HDD></Storage>
        <OS>Windows 10</OS>
        <optional>
            <Monitor>LG 22" Full HD TV</Monitor>
            <Keyboard>Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600</Keyboard>
            <Mouse>Logitech M705 Mouse</Mouse>              
        </optional>
    </Specs>
</entry>
```

XSLT;

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Computer Shop</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">

<th style="text-align:left">Image</th>
<th style="text-align:left">MetaTags</th>
<th style="text-align:left">Brand</th>
<th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
<th style="text-align:left">Description</th>
<th style="text-align:left">Price</th>
<th style="text-align:left">CPU</th>
<th style="text-align:left">GPU</th>
<th style="text-align:left">RAM</th>
<th style="text-align:left">HDD</th>
<th style="text-align:left">SSD</th>
<th style="text-align:left">OS</th>
<th style="text-align:left">Monitor</th>
<th style="text-align:left">Keyboard</th>
<th style="text-align:left">Mouse</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="ComputerShop/entry">
<tr>

<td>
<xsl:value-of select="Image"/>
</td>

<td>
<xsl:value-of select="MetaTags"/>
</td>

<td>
<xsl:value-of select="brand"/>
</td>

<td>
<xsl:value-of select="name"/>
</td>

<td>
<xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
</td>

<td>
<xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
</td>

<td>
<xsl:value-of select="RAM"/>
</td>

<td>
<xsl:value-of select="RAM"/>
</td>

<td>
<xsl:value-of select="HDD"/>
</td>

<td>
<xsl:value-of select="SSD"/>
</td>

<td>
<xsl:value-of select="OS"/>
</td>

<td>
<xsl:value-of select="Monitor"/>
</td>

<td>
<xsl:value-of select="Keyboard"/>
</td>

<td>
<xsl:value-of select="Mouse"/>
</td>





</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>





</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All this creates something that looks like this;

[image]

As you can see, any XML element inside another element won't show up inside the table. I would like any help on how I could fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the path to the element in the `select` attribute.

Instead of doing this....

```
 <xsl:value-of select="RAM"/>
```

You should do this, as `RAM` is under the `Specs` element

```
 <xsl:value-of select="Specs/RAM"/>
```

Similarly, to get the Monitor, for example, do this

```
 <xsl:value-of select="Specs/optional/Monitor"/>
```